# Not able to run Puppeteer in headless mode on shared runner on Gitlab.com

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, puppeteer

I have a private repo which I have set up on Gitlab.com . I have written some test cases for my code including E2E tests which runs on browser. For this I am using `Puppeteer`. My test cases are written in node.js and I am using `Mocha` and `Nyc` for testing and coverage part.

Here is my sample `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
image: node:10.14.2

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - test

test_async:
  stage: test
  before_script:
   - apt-get update
   - apt-get install -yyq ca-certificates
   - apt-get install -yyq libappindicator1 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
   - apt-get install -yyq gconf-service lsb-release wget xdg-utils
   - apt-get install -yyq fonts-liberation

  script:
   - npm install
   - npm i mocha
   - npm i puppeteer
   - npm i nyc
   - npm test
```

Update : 
While running the test now I get the following error on my pipeline build :

```
Failed to launch chrome! spawn chromium ENOENT
```

Browser initialization script :

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      executablePath: 'chromium',
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
      slowMo: 100,
      timeout: 10000
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated. Regards

Comment: I don't have time to debug your problem, but perhaps you could go through google's troubleshooting section, it clearly describes some of the problems running chrome in a constrained environments and suggests solutions https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Thanks @nurettin . It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @nurettin . That doc certainly helped me a lot. Finally by setting my initialization as :

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      slowMo: 100,
      timeout: 10000,
      args: ['--no-sandbox'],

    });
```

Did the trick for me along with the dependencies defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml` .